# why is it not accepting the hidden word?

Tags: python

i created a function that takes in a word and checks it in a file containing all words from the dictionary , accepts the word if it is found else it prints an error message and ask for the word again

```
def getHiddenWord():
    file = open('dictionary.txt')
    found = False
    while found == False:
        hiddenWord = input('Enter the hidden word')
        for word in file.readlines():
            if word.strip().lower() == hiddenWord.lower():
                found = True
                return hiddenWord.lower()
                break
            else:
                 continue
        print('I don\'t have this word in my dictionary please try another word')
```

if i wrote a correct word in the first input it works perfectly but and time after that it keeps looping as intended but it doesn't accept the input taking in consideration that if i wrote the same words the first input it will work and get accepted

Comment: Can you provide example input for when it works and when it keeps looping?

Comment: Note that the `break` after `return` is not needed. Also the `else: continue` can be removed since it is the last thing in the for loop.

Comment: As for your problem, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
file.readlines()
```

can be called only once, when you'll try to call it again on the same opened file it will fail.

Solution: before the loop read the lines and save them into a variable:

```
def getHiddenWord():
    file = open('dictionary.txt')
    lines = file.readlines() # <-- here
    file.close() # <-- here
    found = False
    while found == False:
        hiddenWord = input('Enter the hidden word')
        for word in lines:  # <-- and here
            if word.strip().lower() == hiddenWord.lower():
                found = True
                print(hiddenWord.lower() + ' found!')  # <-- here
                break

        else:
            print('I don\'t have this word in my dictionary please try another word')
```

Further, as Óscar López mentioned in his (now deleted) answer: if you want the game to continue after a word was found you shouldn't `return` - just print "success" and `break`

Comment: That's great. could you just get rid of the break statement and whole else block?

Comment: @Tomerikoo good point - I updated the code respectively, thanks!

Comment: OK now the break is necessary but please get rid of `else: continue`. It hurts my eyes! :)

Comment: @alfasin you broke the code. Now `'I don\'t have this word in my dictionary please try another word'` will be printed even if the word was found.

Comment: That's true. could put it back with return, or put the print in an else block for the for loop

Comment: @CrafterKolyan true, we can put the `else` as complementary to the `for` loop, this way it will execute only of the for-loop finished iterating all the words and didn't find the requested word.

Comment: Found=True will close the while loop, so I think it's better to put a while True to continue the game and remove found variable. If the scope is to close everything after the word is found, then just return instead of break

Comment: @Tomerikoo correct again - added a `close` command. Personally I'm used to using `with` so it takes care of closing the file for me.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to convert the file into a `set` once and the just use `in` to check if the input is there:

```
def get_hidden_word():
    with open('dictionary.txt') as fp:
        words = set(w.strip().lower() for w in fp)

    while True:
        guess = input('Enter the hidden word').strip().lower()
        if guess in words:
            return guess

        print("I don't have this word in my dictionary please try another word")
```